# SAP UI5 Dynamic id for core:HTML appexcharts div + synchronization issue

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5

I have a ui5 application that contains appexcharts, I have faced two issues so far,

**The first one** is that in some cases I have dynamic number of charts that should be added based on oData number of records, so I tried this

View:

```
<List id="donutList" items="{myList>/}">
  <CustomListItem>
     <HBox>
        <core:HTML></core:HTML>
     </HBox>
  <CustomListItem>
</List>
```

Controller:

```
var listItems = this.getView().byId("donutList").getItems();
var oModel = this.getView().getModel("myList");
for(var i =0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
    var sPath = listItems[i].getBindingContextPath();
    var item = oModel.getProperty(sPath);
    listItems[i].getContent()[0].getItems()[0].setContent("<div id='donutChart" + item.id + "'></div>");
}
```

when I use the setContent method it does set the content but when I try onAfterRendering it always gives me an error that it is null, for example this line returns null

```
console.log(document.querySelector("#donutChart" + item.id ));
```

so, is there a way where I can write the dynamic id in the xml? is there a syntax to add dynamic id to this line? I've searched allot and didn't find a result that works

```
<core:HTML content=“&lt;div id=&quot; ID-HERE &quot; &gt;&lt;/div&gt;”></core:HTML>
```

**My Second question** is that I have synchronization issue with appexcharts, 9 of 10 times the afterRendering function is executed before the oData retrieved from the backend, although I'm adding the afterRendering function inside the success part of oData read.

```
that.getView().addEventDelegate({
    onAfterRendering: that.onRenderingAppex()
}, that);
```

I tried the async await but it created more issues than it solved. is there another way to make sure that the oData comes before the afterRendering excuted?

Sorry for the so many questions but I have been trying to solve this for two weeks without succeeding.
and thank you in advance.